# Finding the Most Common Words in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I'm writing a function to output the most common word in a Binary Search Tree but it outputs the word in the top of the bst in alphabetical order rather than most common word.

for example:

Input: abc abc abc abc xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz xyz

Output: abc

I really don't know what the issue is, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
void WordAnalyzer::findCommon(TreeNode* root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        findCommon(root->left);
        if (prev != NULL) {
            if (root->data == prev->data) {
                currCount++;
            }
            else {
                currCount = 1;
            }
        }

        if (currCount > maxCount) {
            maxCount = currCount;
            maxWord = root->data;
        }
        prev = root;
        findCommon(root->right);
    }
}

string WordAnalyzer::getMostCommonWord() {
    findCommon(root);
    return maxWord;
}
```

Comment: I am confused about a BST containing the same value multiple times. Please provide a [mre] which sets up such a tree and then demonstrates the behaviour you describe.

Comment: I disagree. The question is crystal clear. OP has a custom BST (that can contain multiple values, this is known as a *multiset*) and they are trying to find the most frequent element in this BST.

Comment: It’s difficult to say what the bug is without knowing how you arrange the equal elements. Recursion and mutable state is not a good combination, though. (Why not keep a counter in the nodes instead of inserting each key multiple times, or — if they contain more than the string — a vector?)

Comment: Without a [mcve], we're just guessing.  My best guess is you have a bug in your code.  I was unable to reproduce the misbehavior.

Comment: IMHO, each node should have the word and a counter variable.  If the word already exists in the tree, increment the counter.  No need to store duplicates; it increases the complexity of the program.

Comment: You need to present a bit more code. The part you've pasted looks OK, except that `getMostCommonWord` doesn't initialise the visitor context variables (`currCount`, `maxCount`, `maxWord` and `prev`). Correct initialisation is crucial, so you need to show the part of the code which does that. (`WordAnalyzer`'s constructor, perhaps?) It would also be useful to see the definition of `TreeNode` to validate the use of `==` between `data` elements. A few comments would probably help people not used to this algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from the code how and where `currCount` is initialized, but if it is not initialized explicitly before this code runs, you have an undefined behavior.

When looking at the first (leftest) element in your BST, you set `prev = root`, but you do not set `currCount`, then when you visit the next element, you increase `currCount` by 1, but you never gave it an initial value, and it can contain basically any "garbage" value.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a map with key as "word" and value as "count". Traverse the BST using any traversal (like Inorder), and increment the counts for corresponnding "word" in map. Then when whole traversal is over, check in your main function, the word with the most count in Map.

Here is a quick reference if you are not familiar with the Map data structure.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/